# how do i stretch the background image to cover the entire activity page in Android Virtual Device

Tags: android-layout

Below is the snippet code to my Loginactivity.Its only covering half page.Please suggest how to stretch it to cover the entire page.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher5"

tools:context="com.ericsson.myapplication3.LoginActivity">
```

Comment: It is covering full screen. Set color instead of image as background and try. Remove padding if required.

Comment: I want to set image only as background.and its just covering the middle part of the screen and not the entire screen.

Comment: Use android:background="@android:color/black"  and see how it goes.